# IE DIV hover area not the same. until I add a background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Basically I made a imagemap using DIV/CSS/JS

My rollover links are setup like this:

```
<a class="rollover" id="01" href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="mapLinkBox" id="mapLink01">&nbsp;</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.mapLinkBox {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
#mapLink01 {
    bottom: 31px;
    left: 35px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

But in IE, the link hover area is being affected by something and isn't working properly. What could be causing the problem?

jQuery used for hover:

```
$(".rollover").each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {

    },function() {

    });
})
```

Comment: Try assigning `width`, `height`, `bottom` and `left` onto the `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mouseover`, I've had problems with `hover` in the past.  Also you can clean up your code a bit, you have some redundant selectors:

```
$('.rollover').mouseover(function() {

}).mouseout(function() {

});
```

Comment: The problem ended up being fadeTo. I didn't explain that the popups were absolute positioned and sitting on top of all the rollovers. The Popups were still interactive even with the z-index set and opacity at 0. I needed the popups to be removed from the display. So using fadeOut worked out in this case.

Answer (score 0):

While a `<div>` element is a block, an `<a>` element is inline by default. This can make it's box behave differently from what you'd expect when trying to imagine how its box will render and behave.

Try setting `display:block` for the `.rollover` element and see if that fixes it for you. Do take note that it won't function as text anymore (obviously) but you're appending a `<div>` inside anyway, and I'm assuming that's the layout you're aiming for.

You should even be able to get away with removing the `<div>` inside the `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".rollover").on('hover', function(e) {
  if(e.type == 'mouseenter') {
     // do something for mouseover
  } else {
     // do something for mouseout
  }
});
```

or

```
$(".rollover").hover(function(e) {
     // do something for mouseover
  }, function() {
     // do something for mouseout
  }
});
```

You don't need loop to bind hover effenct to `.rollover`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I would swap the `<div>` outside of the `<a>`.

According to [HTML 4.01 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A)  may only contain inline elements, with a  being a block element.

Although most browsers have gotten better at handling the box model, IE is notorious for still being an idiot when it comes to the box model (especially IE6-IE8).

Try swapping your elements (change your css and jquery to match the new dom).

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being fadeTo. I didn't explain that the popups were absolute positioned and sitting on top of all the rollovers. The Popups were still interactive even with the z-index set and opacity at 0. I needed the popups to be removed from the display. So using fadeOut worked out in this case.

Thanks for everyone help on this though. You guys rock!